# .htaccess rule gives 500 error for php file

Tags: apache-2.2, php, .htaccess

I used a stackoverflow answer to come up with what I was trying to do.
I want requests to http://myserver.com/book/1234 to actually show the content form php file http://myserver.com/book.php?id=1234

So my .htaccess looks like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^book/(.*)$ /book.php?id=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

Notice the bottom two lines allow me to use url's like http://myserver.php/login to actually pull up http://myserver.php/login.php   This is working correctly.
But I get a 500 Error when I try calling http://myserver.com/book.php?id=1234  What is wrong?

Comment: You started your question by saying that you *want requests to http://myserver.com/book/1234 to actually show the content form php file http://myserver.com/book.php?id=1234* but then you ended by stating  the  URL `http://myserver.com/book.php?id=1234` doesnt work.  Does `http://myserver.com/book/1234` work for you? and can you clarify your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question seems to have conflicting statements, but assuming this statement

> I want requests to http://myserver.com/book/1234 to actually show the content form php file http://myserver.com/book.php?id=1234

is what you want.
If you request `http://myserver.com/book.php?id=1234` - then your server will flip out based on your current .htaccess. The reason is you should only be performing this directive

```
RewriteRule ^book/(.*)$ /book.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Under certain conditions, e.g. if the URL is not for a real file or directory.
This directive

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]*)$
```

Is telling apache not only go ahead and do the rewrite when a request has the form

```
some_URI?id=some_number
```

but in fact the rewrite will ONLY occur when the request has that form.
When a request is for `http://myserver.com/book.php?id=1234` you can prevent the rewrite occurring with

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

So then you `.htaccess` should look like

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^book/(.*)$ /book.php?id=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

Comment: Awesome. That did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this locally, and it works. Make sure your apache.conf allows the overrides you have specified in your .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/book\/([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^ /book.php?id=%1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```